# Issue with stub a function that returns promise - mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, stub

I am new to writing unit tests in mocha chai. I have one function called appStore:

```
public appStore(name) {
    return this.connector.findOne(name).then((record) => {
      if (!record) {
        throw new Error("Record not found");
      }
      return record.data;
    });
  }
```

Here record.data is an object which contains:

```
{ 
    a: "ValueA", 
    b: "ValueB", 
    c: "ValueC" 
}
```

I tried to stub the function. But not able to get it properly.

```
import myClass from "testClass.service";
describe("MyModule", () => {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  let valTest;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const userObj = { 
        a: "ValueA", 
        b: "ValueB", 
        c: "ValueC" 
    };
    valTest = sandbox.stub(myClass , "appStore").returns(userObj );
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  it("myfunc1 is a proxy for myfunc2", () => {

     expect(myClass.appStore("dataname")).to.eql(userObj );
  });
});
```

Please correct me if i am wrong, since I am beginner to this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would not want to stub methods on a class, but only on a single object of that class. To return a promise, use `resolves()` rather than `returns()`.

```
import myClass from "testClass.service";
describe("MyModule", () => {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  const myInstance = new myClass();
  let valTest;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const userObj = { 
        a: "ValueA", 
        b: "ValueB", 
        c: "ValueC" 
    };
    valTest = sandbox.stub(myInstance , "appStore").resolves(userObj );
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  it("myfunc1 is a proxy for myfunc2", () => {

     expect(myInstance.appStore("dataname")).to.eql(userObj );
  });
});
```

If you really want to stub a nonstatic method for all objects derived from a particular class, you would do it on the prototype.

```
sandbox.stub(myClass.prototype, "appStore").resolves(userObj);
```

The `appStore` method still does not exist on the class itself, but you can verify that the stub works using any object.

```
expect((new myClass).appStore("dataname")).to.eql(userObj);
```

Comment: In my class, i have already created instance like export default new GetStore(); . So here in this scenario how can i use this?

Comment: Thanks. So is the expectation failing or are you getting some other error?

Comment: Yes its failing & throwing error: AssertionError: expected {} to deeply equal { Object (a, b, ...) }